TensorFlow Federated (TFF) Compatibility with Python 3.10.x and TensorFlow 2.14.0
I am currently working with TensorFlow 2.14.0 and Python 3.10.x and I am looking to integrate TensorFlow Federated (TFF) into my project. However, I am unsure about the compatibility of TFF with this specific combination of Python and TensorFlow versions.
I noticed that TensorFlow Federated (TFF) version 0.75 is not explicitly compatible with TensorFlow 2.14.0, according to the documentation. Therefore, I am seeking guidance on which version of TensorFlow Federated (TFF) would be suitable and compatible with Python 3.10.x and TensorFlow 2.14.0.
Could someone provide recommendations on the compatible version of TensorFlow Federated (TFF) that aligns with TensorFlow 2.14.0 and Python 3.10.x? In addition, any insights or tips on integrating TFF with this environment would be greatly appreciated.
Additionally after importing tff 0.75.0 version, I am continuously getting such errors:

ImportError: cannot import name “Model” from “tensorflow_federated.python.learning” (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/init.py)


According to the installation documentation, you need to install python3 with sudo apt install python3-dev python3-pip then create/activate a virtual environment. Finally, you need to install TFF by the pip install --upgrade tensorflow-federated command.

Regarding the version, the latest TFF version is 0.75 and the TF version is 2.16 as of today. I would pick the latest in your case if no old version has to be kept.
